# Custom Thread run() not invoke via Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-aop

> I could not able to invoke the thread run() via Spring aop , ie
>   Application not invoked the Aspect code .Any suggestion?
>
> Spring 4.0/ Java 1.7

spring-context.xml

```
    <bean id="pocServiceAspect" class="kbsql.com.poc.POCServiceAspect" />
<aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="pocServiceAspectId" ref="pocServiceAspect">

         <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAround"
                expression="execution(* kbsql.com.poc.WorkThread.threadRun(..) )" />
            <aop:around method="aroundServiceExtractData"
                pointcut-ref="pointCutAround" /> 
        </aop:aspect>

    </aop:config>
```

> Given below is Java code to execute :

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        //To get the data using query.
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context-poc.xml");

        Class<?> myclass=WorkThread.class;
        List<AbsThread> list= new ArrayList<AbsThread>();
        for(int i=0;i<5 ;i++) {
            AbsThread t=(AbsThread)context.getBean(myclass.getSimpleName());
            list.add(t);

        }
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
            AbsThread abst=(AbsThread)list.get(i);
            Thread t = new Thread(abst);
            t.start();
        }

    }

 //     
}
```

> Given below is Abstract Thread Class:

```
     public abstract class AbsThread implements Runnable{
        @Autowired protected ApplicationContext context;
        protected String name;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void run() {
            try{
                System.out.println(" Abstract Thread starts "); 
                threadRun();    
                System.out.println(" Abstract Thread ends ");   

            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Exception "+ex);
            }finally{

            }
        }

        protected abstract void threadRun() throws Exception;
    }
```

> Given below is Thread Implementation:

```
 @Component("WorkThread")
 public class WorkThread extends AbsThread{

@Override
protected void threadRun() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Thread Starts Id : "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.out.println("Logic invoked Sucessfully");
    System.out.println("Thread Ends Id : "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
```

}

> The Aspect Code given below

```
 public class POCServiceAspect {
    public void aroundServiceExtractData(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
            try{
                System.out.println("Aspect Starts");
                Date startTime = new Date();
                joinPoint.proceed();    
                System.out.println("Aspect ends");

            }catch(Exception ex){
                throw ex;
            }   
        }
```

Why aspect is not invoked  when i am starting the thread?

Comment: Because AOP is proxy-based. It can only intercept calls to public bean methods made from outside the bean. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Comment: is there any alternate approach for this issue?

Comment: I think if you configure things so that Spring uses AspectJ and load-time weaving, you can get this to work...

Comment: @moilejter Could you please explain briefly or do you  have any reference or example.

Comment: how about: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-transaction/spring-transactions-on-non-public-methods-with-load-time-weaving/ - you don't need the transaction annotations - but once you enable load-time weaving using aspectj, i think your example ought to work...